# how to enable gd image library in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, gd

I'm using wamp 64. While manipulating images, it shows the error:

> gd image library is not supported

How do I enable gd image library in codeigniter?

Comment: or use xampp, never had this issue with it

Comment: thanks man,,  worked while uncommenting extension_dir = "ext"

Answer (score 0):

To activate the GD library, go to your WAMP’s PHP.ini file, which can be found by clicking on the WAMP icon in your system tray. Go to “Config files”, and you’ll find it in there.

Next, in PHP.ini, search for the following line of code:

;extension=php_gd2.dll

Now remove the semicolon from the beginning of that line, so that the line now looks like this:

extension=php_gd2.dll

Restart WAMP, and your GD library will be activated.

Comment: i had removed semicolon from php.ini file still not working